# Serializing/de-serializing with different classes using Msgpack (Java API)

Tags: java, msgpack

I'm currently experimenting with Msgpack to de-serialize an object graph using Msgpack but I am hitting problems.

At the moment I have a simple hierachy consisting of two classes: `BaseMessage` and `PersonNew`. `BaseMessage` has a single Long field `id` with getters and setters. `PersonNew` has String fields `name` and `email` and inherits from `BaseMessage`.

Originally `PersonOld` class had the `id` field and it serialized/de-serialized fine. However when tring to de-serialize from `PersonOld` (which had the `id`) to `PersonNew` class (which inherits the `id` from `BaseMessage`) I'm being hit with the error:

```
org.msgpack.MessageTypeException: Unexpected raw value
```

All the fields I'm using are private.

Below is the sample code:

```java
    PersonOld personOld = new PersonOld();
    personOld.setName("person");
    personOld.setEmail("person@email.com");

    MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
    msgpack.register(PersonNew.class);
    msgpack.register(PersonOld.class);

    // Serialize using old person class
    byte[] personBytes = msgpack.write(personOld);

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(personBytes);
    Unpacker unpacker = msgpack.createUnpacker(in);

    // Deserialize using new person class
    PersonNew deserializePerson = unpacker.read(PersonNew.class);
```

The reason I'd like to de-serialize to a newer class is because I want to see if it's possible to have older serialized data (e.g. in a persisted message queue) be compatible with newer classes (e.g. in case of class updates). I have attempted to even use the `@Optional` annotation on the `id` of the `BaseMessage` class but still doesn't work.

Is it possible at all to de-serialize with a different class despite having the same fields?

Regards,

SNK

Comment: What does your PersonOld class look like?